# How is a block found in pools via “shares” given to miners?

Tags: mining-pool-shares

It is stated that the mining pool’s server assigns each miner a specific set of cryptographic calculations called “shares.

Can someone explain in detail how these “shares” fit into finding a solution or block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pool sets its members an easier target than the current Bitcoin network target. Every time a pool member finds a block with a hash less than the pool target they submit the block to the pool controller and thereby earn a "share". The pool controller checks that the submitted block has a hash less than the pool target and that the block's coinbase pays the pool controller (or some equivalent rule).

So the "share" is just a way of keeping track of hashrate contributed to the pool by each member.

The process for mining is independent of target. So occasionally, the hash of one of the submitted blocks is not only less than the easy pool target, it is also less than the harder Bitcoin network target, so the pool controller can submit that block to the Bitcoin network, receive the block reward and pay out pool members based on the number of shares won by each pool member recently.

The exact details of pool operation depend on the specific network protocols used by the pool. A popular protocol is [stratum v2](https://braiins.com/stratum-v2). You'll see that the submitted block itself is sometimes referred to as a "share" or "job". 1 completed job == 1 submitted block == 1 share.

Comment: Great answer !  Thanks !  If you like to add more details anywhere please do so…again thanks that is certainly something I did not know.

Comment: Follow up question…is the pool target the same for all miners?

Comment: I think the pool target would have to be the same for all members of a pool, otherwise I believe it would unfairly disadvantage some and drive them to other fairer pools.